# How do I prevent byobu from duplicating text on all splits?

Tags: byobu

Recently I started using Byobu, and I'm having a problem with each split just being a duplicate of the original. Whatever I type in one split appears in all of the others. I'm also using Byobu on another computer and do not have this problem. Is this a bug or did I accidentally modify my setup somehow?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should mention that I have deleted the .byobu folder, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description, you're using byobu with the GNU Screen backend, where "splits" are not really handled very well.

Byobu's tmux backend provides a *much* better experience when trying splits.

You can switch your backend by running:

```
byobu-select-backend
```

Or you can manually launch with either backend, using `byobu-tmux` or `byobu-screen`.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of Byobu.*

Comment: That is interesting. Thank you. I tried that, but it gives me an error:

    'exec: 141: tmux: not found'

Edit: Nevermind, it just wasn't installed ;)

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Great program by the way. Really useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a quick cheat sheet for working with splits in Byobu:**

- C-a + Tab - Cycle split windows
- C-a + C - Create new tab
- C-a + {Number} - Select the tab number for the active split window.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really have a problem with navigating splits or windows. The problem is that text is duplicating on all splits. Each split doesn't constitute a unique terminal instance, which seems to defeat the purpose of having splits!

Comment: That is what you solve by creating new tabs and cycling them for each window. If you just create splits without opening different tabs, you'll of course be left with the same terminal in both splits.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Didn't realize that. I didn't seem to have that problem when I first started using Byobu at home... maybe I accidentally opened a new tab or something. In any case, creating a new tab did solve the problem. Thanks!